# pipe to cuda not working stable diffusion

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

stable diffusion inside a jupyter notebook with cuda 12
Nvidea studio driver on the host Win 11.
PyTorch in other projects runs just fine no problems with cuda.
My jupyterlab sits inside a WSL ubuntu.
My problem I cannot run pipe.to("cuda") with stable diffusion, the image generator.
Which I like to run local for faster generation.

```
# inside jupyterlab cell:
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
```

although I enter my key hf_asfasfd...  I cannot verify login is accepted
but I guess that's normal? kind of weird

```
# inside the next cell:
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
```

--> **prints cuda**

```
# in another cell:
import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
from PIL import Image
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", torch_dtype=torch.float16)
```

i can see it downloaded the model so login was OK i guess..

```
pipe = pipe.to("cuda")
```

**kernel time out I got a 3080TX 12Gig memory stays low no indication it loaded

The fans of the cards also don't spin up which it should if it worked**
I also raised the timeout for jupyterlab to 10 minutes with no effect.
The time-out doesn't show any error in the console or in the web page.

```
# cell that doesn't get executed:
prompt = "a photo of a cat riding a horse on mars"
image = pipe(prompt).images[0]  
image.show()
```

last cell never gets executed
I have altered the config to perform kernel restart after 10 minutes to wait if it takes longer but this has no effect ( when the kernel dies eventually on the Linux prompt I get  AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel ) but no other errors on the screen or on the web page of the notebook. And this error is just that the timeout (increased to 10 minutes) has passed, so it's hanging

installed all the latest versions of transformers, and diffusers, scipy

Any ideas of what this could be, this code runs fine on google colab.
I know pytorch cuda can work on my machine but it isn't loading the pipeline here